# Do some languages have significantly more or fewer idioms than others?

Tags: lexicon

Among the well-attested languages for which large corpora have been gathered, does the number of idiomatic expressions per language vary significantly?   Are there fewer idioms in some languages than in others?  Do certain factors affect the number of idioms in a language, such as the number of people who speak the language or the number of different cultures in which the language is spoken fluently?

Comment: I think there are some languages which have fewer idioms than the others affected by social factors almost.

Comment: For a real quantitative answer, you'll need a widely-applicable definition of ***idiom*** with severable testable characteristics, to distinguish idiomaticity from _irregularity_ and _non-compositionality,_ for instance.

Comment: Would SIL's definition do the trick?   http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAnIdiom.htm

Comment: Yeah, that'll do fine, I think. Though notice that the properties were all negative - they're **non-compositional** and they have **non-productive syntax**. That means they have to be compared to compositional and productive constructions, which means several levels of analysis and no obvious way to search for them. [WALS](http://wals.info/chapter), for instance, doesn't have a chapter on idioms, though it has two on suppletion.